# Installation of VSTO Office addin using WiX

Tags: c#, wix, vsto, ms-office, office-addins

I've made an Excel addin and tried to install it using this answer:
[How do you use WiX to deploy VSTO 3.0 addins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532447/how-do-you-use-wix-to-deploy-vsto-3-0-addins/678290#678290)

It doesn't work this way and I figured out that when Visual Studio deploys addins it creates additional registry keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTO\SolutionMetadata. I've added corresponding keys manually to my installer and it works now, but i suppose that it's not an elegant/safe method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmm. Are you able to say what happens if you try to install your Wix MSI (before you add those other registry keys) on a box that does not have VS installed?

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug in VSTO (fixed in SP1).

See more info here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eac0aa15-96bb-4d21-bd69-a987e6c95f40/vsto-40-addins-issue-hkeycurrentusersoftwaremicrosoftvstosolutionmetadata?forum=vsto