# How do you install VS Tools For Office Runtime from my WiX installer? I'm getting "waiting for another install to complete" deadlock

Tags: wix, windows-installer, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm writing an installer for my Office Outlook add-in using WiX. The add-in itself requires [VS Tools For Office Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=56961) to be installed. So I thought to install it as a custom-action from within my own WiX installer:

```
<Binary Id='idBinVstorRedist' SourceFile='Sources\vstor_redist.exe' />

<CustomAction Id="idCSVstorRedist" Return="asyncWait" HideTarget="no" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand="" BinaryKey="idBinVstorRedist" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="idCSVstorRedist" After="InstallInitialize">
    NOT Installed
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

where the `vstor_redist.exe` itself is part of my MSI package:

[image]

But when I run my installer it deadlocks in the `VstorRedist` with the message: "Waiting for another install to complete":

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the VSTO Office Runtime is installed, we’ll add condition and two `RegistrySearch` elements. `RegistrySearch`, does exactly what the name implies, it searches the target machines’ registry for a specific key and value.

```
<Property Id="VSTORUNTIMEREDIST">
  <RegistrySearch 
    Id="VSTORuntimeRedist" 
    Root="HKLM" 
    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R" 
    Name="Version" 
    Type="raw" />
</Property>
<Condition 
  Message="The Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime is not installed. 
  Please download and install from 
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20479.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR VSTORUNTIMEREDIST>="10.0.30319"]]>
</Condition>
```

Read more about that in the [Creating WiX installation projects for VSTO-based Office add-ins](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/11/13/wix-installation-vsto-office-addin/) article.

Also, you may find the [How do you use WiX to deploy VSTO 3.0 addins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532447/how-do-you-use-wix-to-deploy-vsto-3-0-addins) article helpful.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure this is what I was asking for. Your code shows how to display an error for the end user if VSTO runtime is not installed. I'm asking how to install it. As for "How do you use WiX to deploy VSTO 3.0 addins" link -- I'm sorry, I'm probably not following it, but where does it show how to install VSTO runtime in there?

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the fact that your custom action is set to run After="InstallInitialize". I'm trialing running a batch script to install the runtime after checking if it isn't present or not and it appears to be working okay for me like  this

```
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RunBatch" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<CustomAction Id="RunBatch"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="ignore"
              Impersonate="no"
              ExeCommand="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /C &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]vsto_runtime.bat&quot;"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
```

This is not the recommended way to install prerequisites but after having issues with creating a bundle, this is a working short term fix for me

Hopefully this is of some use for you.